A faster way to test 32bpp DDBs for a valid Alpha channel
Windows GDI object HBITMAP does not contain any flags that mark it as having a valid alpha channel.
It is possible to obtain some information about it through the function GetObject() which can return the BITMAP structure.  This structure contains the bmBitsPixel field that can be used to eliminate bitmap formats that are less than 32bpp and thus cannot contain the alpha channel.
When bmBitsPixel==32 the format of the bitmap can be 0RGB or ARGB and as far as I know, the only way to distinguish between these two cases is checking ALL pixel values for the presence of non-zero Alpha value (please correct me if I am wrong).  Even if 1 pixel has a non-zero Alpha value, Windows treats it as an ARGB bitmap.
This determination has profound consequences for ICON handling and the behavior of some function such as, but not limited to, the DrawIcon()and DrawIconEx().  These functions ignore or account for the monochrome mask (ICONINFO.hbmMask) that contains the transparency data for the entire icon, depending on some flags and whether the format of the icon's color bitmap is 0RGB or ARGB.
The code below performs the classification of a DDB bitmap as 0RGB or ARGB by shrinking it to 1x1px and testing for non-zero Alpha value.
Q: Is there a more optimal way to perform such classification ?
Note: I heard that bringing DDB's pixel data to User Mode is costly.
BOOL HasAlpha(HBITMAP hBmp)
{
    BOOL res = FALSE;
    BITMAP bmp = {0};
    GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    if (bmp.bmBitsPixel == 32)
    {
        HDC hDCsrc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
        HBITMAP hBmpOldSrc = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDCsrc, hBmp);
        HDC hDCdst = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCsrc);
        HBITMAP hBmpDst = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCsrc, 1, 1);
        HBITMAP hBmpOldDst = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDCdst, hBmpDst);
        PDWORD pPixel;

        SetStretchBltMode(hDCdst, STRETCH_ORSCANS); //STRETCH_ANDSCANS
        StretchBlt(hDCdst, 0, 0, 1, 1, hDCsrc, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
           
        if (pPixel = (PDWORD)GetBMBits(hDCdst, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        {
            if (*pPixel & 0xFF000000)
                res = TRUE;

            _aligned_free(pPixel);
        }

        SelectObject(hDCsrc, hBmpOldSrc);
        DeleteObject(SelectObject(hDCdst, hBmpOldDst));
        DeleteDC(hDCsrc);
        DeleteDC(hDCdst);
    }

    return res;
}

LPVOID GetBMBits(HDC hDC, UINT usage)    //When done must free the result with _aligned_free().  Also, usage = DIB_RGB_COLORS or DIB_PAL_COLORS
{
    LPVOID pMem = NULL;
    BITMAPINFO BmpInf[2]; BmpInf[0].bmiHeader.biBitCount = 0; BmpInf[0].bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    HBITMAP hBmp = HBITMAP(SelectObject(hDC, CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 0, 0)));  //Push out the bitmap that was in DC

    if (GetDIBits(hDC, hBmp, 0, 1, NULL, &BmpInf[0], usage))
    {
        if (pMem = _aligned_malloc(BmpInf[0].bmiHeader.biSizeImage, sizeof(DWORD)))
        {
            if (!GetDIBits(hDC, hBmp, 0, BmpInf[0].bmiHeader.biHeight, pMem, &BmpInf[0], usage))
            {
                _aligned_free(pMem);
                pMem = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hDC, hBmp));
    return pMem;
}


You don't need to copy your HBITMAP to a temporary 1x1 bitmap just to access its pixels. If your source bitmap is a DIB then you already have access to its raw pixel data in the BITMAP::bmBits field from GetObject(). Otherwise, you can use GetDIBits() instead. Either way, you can then simply iterate the raw pixels looking at their Alpha bits. Always prefer to access a bitmap's raw scan lines when performance is an issue.

They are DDBs, BITMAP.bmBits== 0.  GetDIBits() incurs GDI to Usermode transition and mem pages mapping.  I am already using it and I'd like to avoid it.

This may or may not be meaningful in your case, but be aware that a fully black 0RGB image and a fully transparent ARGB image have identical binary representations. They are indiscriminate.

"Note: I heard that bringing DDB's pixel data to User Mode is costly."  Have you measured to see whether it's actually too costly for your use case?  Do you need to quickly check zillions of bitmaps?  If you're checking the same one over and over, can you cache the result?  In most cases, the DDB pixel data came from user mode.  Can you check it once when it's created?  Can you convert the bitmap to whichever form you prefer and then never worry again about testing it?

Working with HBITMAP is messy, it's an old handle back in the days where no alpha was there. Use GDI+ or, better, WIC.

@MichaelChourdakis The question is about the problem where you get an HBITMAP from somewhere. You don't get to choose, and neither GDI+ nor the WIC help with that.

if you have HBITMAP as input code can be next
BOOL HasAlpha(PBYTE pvBits, ULONG cb)
{
    pvBits += 3;// pointer to alpha byte
    cb >>= 2;
    do 
    {
        if (*pvBits)
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (pvBits += 4, --cb);

    return cb;
}

BOOL HasAlpha(HBITMAP hBmp)
{
    BITMAP bm;
    if (GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm) && 
        1 == bm.bmPlanes && 
       32 == bm.bmBitsPixel)
    {
        ULONG cb = bm.bmWidthBytes * bm.bmHeight;

        if (bm.bmBits)
        {
            return HasAlpha((PBYTE)bm.bmBits, cb);
        }
        
        if (bm.bmBits = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cb))
        {
            if (cb = GetBitmapBits(hBmp, cb, bm.bmBits))
            {
                cb = HasAlpha((PBYTE)bm.bmBits, cb);
            }
            LocalFree(bm.bmBits);
            return cb;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}


as noted Simon Mourier some system DLLs (ExplorerFrame, shell32, Taskbar, twinui.pcshell, Windows.Internal.Shell.Broker, Windows.Storage, Windows.UI.CredDialogController) have internal function:
HRESULT _DoesBitmapHaveAlpha(_In_ HBITMAP hbmp, _Out_ bool * pHave);

which have similar implementation:
first call GetObject, then GetDC(0) and GetDIBits. it not check for BITMAP::bmBits which can be already not 0, so we not need call GetDIBits. i use GetBitmapBits instead GetDIBits. then function check only alpha byte from bmBits and decide that alpha exist if some alpha byte not 0. i bit optimize my implementation, after i look for system code:
was
BOOL HasAlpha(PULONG pvBits, ULONG cb)
{
    cb >>= 2;
    do 
    {
        if (*pvBits++ >> 24)
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (--cb);

    return cb;
}

and i replace it to
BOOL HasAlpha(PBYTE pvBits, ULONG cb)
{
    pvBits += 3;// pointer to alpha byte
    cb >>= 2;
    do 
    {
        if (*pvBits)
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (pvBits += 4, --cb);

    return cb;
}

sense here - no more need >> 24 on DWORD or & 0XFF000000 - we just read single appha byte, instead ARGB dword.
but my code stop loop after just found first not 0 alpha, when system implementation always itterate over all image bytes unconditionally ( which is not the best)

the _DoesBitmapHaveAlpha is not exported, so we can not call it from any dll.
it always called from anothe not exported api
HRESULT CreateBitmapFromIconWithAlpha(_In_ HICON hi, _In_ int size, _Out_ HBITMAP * pbmp);

which can be called from several locations, as example
HRESULT _CreateBitmapFromSystemImageListWithAlpha(
    int iIndex, //= SHMapPIDLToSystemImageListIndex
    int dwFlags,
    int size,
    HBITMAP *);
HRESULT CShellItem::_GetIcon(SIZE s, int dwFlags, bool b, HBITMAP *);
virtual HRESULT CShellItem::GetSharedBitmap(SIZE s, int dwFlags, ISharedBitmap * *);


I agree that "if you have src bitmap data - you already have the pointer to pvBits  - so not need call any GDI API at all" and your code is close to optimal.  UnfortunatelypvBits==0 so calling GDI is unavoidable.  The only issue is whether the pixel scanning is done in User Mode by our code or by GDI in kernel mode.  Transferring data across this boundary is expensive.

@GeorgeRobinson but you need only one call to GetObject and if !bmBits second call to GetBitmapBits and all. and compare this with your code. how many calls (in loop!) you do

@GeorgeRobinson UnfortunatelypvBits==0 - but from where you get HBITMAP ?

I do not have any loops in my code

Where I get the HBITMAP is out of scope of this question.  It is not a DIB Section. It is a DDB.

@GeorgeRobinson StretchBlt ? this is for what ?

@GeorgeRobinson - It is not a DIB Section. It is a DDB. - ok. i write implementation (fix first version for check - if bm.bmBits exist already).

StretchBlt() is called only once to condense the HBITMAP into one pixel.  Unfortunately getting this pixel's FULL data from GDI involves setting up the data transfer from kernel mode to user mode and that is more expensive then your entire loop in user mode.

@GeorgeRobinson you can compare speed of 2 ways

I upvoted your code for remembering about the existence of GetBitmapBits() API.  Unfortunately this function is as slow as GetDIBits() since it involves setting up the data transfer from kernel mode to user mode and associated mem page mapping. This setup is slower than the entire pixel scanning loop !

@GeorgeRobinson are you test this or guess only ?

@GeorgeRobinson no bug, in case 32bpp it already multiple 4. no pad in case 32bitmap - each pixel - 4 bytes

Right. I ran into this problem with 24bpp.

@GeorgeRobinson but code optimized for 32bpp. for 24 of course can be pad

Right, that's why I deleted the comment about the 24bpp and padding

Since Windows uses premultiplied alpha there's another property you could check as well: If the RGB part of the color value is non-zero but the Alpha part is zero, the image doesn't have an Alpha channel. This potentially allows you to terminate the loop earlier depending on your input. Besides, willfully constructing BOOL values that are neither TRUE nor FALSE is a crime.

@IInspectable potentially allows you to terminate the loop earlier probably. despite if Alpha part is zero, no sense have non zero RGB ?

@IInspectable Besides, willfully constructing BOOL values that are neither TRUE nor FALSE is a crime i think that bool, BOOL, BOOLEAN - type which have only 2 values - 0 and not 0. so any logical compare with 0. never compare with 1 or TRUE. so all not 0 values is equal

FWIW, Shell32.dll's internal implementation ("_DoesBitmapHasAlpha", present in other Windows dlls) is 99% the same as RbMm's one https://i.imgur.com/mGftKr7.png

@SimonMourier - ha-ha - i search for _DoesBitmapHasAlpha and can not found such name.. strange, nothing understand, why i not found. only after some time i understand that real name is _DoesBitmapHaveAlpha

@SimonMourier: Excellent job!  It has not occurred to me to load Shel32.dll into IDA and look for an internal function like that.  Too bad it is undocumented, unexported and spelled grammatically.  I'd love to call it.

@GeorgeRobinson - it not exported, so you can not call it, even if know about it

@RbMm:  Please add Simon's answer to your answer (including the IDA disassembly) and mention him in your reply.

@GeorgeRobinson - yes, no problem, if Simon's not do this by self too. only let me give some time for research, i want look for it more
